# Query results that have less than X characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, character

Some submitters have submitted location strings that are too short.
How can I query them to remove them in phpMyAdmin?

The query would look like this (ending is obviously pseudo code):

```
SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'location' 
AND `meta_value` HAS LESS THAN 10 CHARACTERS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'location' AND CHAR_LENGTH(meta_value) < 10
```